# Extracting baseline values from long format data frame

Tags: r

I have a following data frame, representing longitudinal data:

```
 df<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), AGE = c(59, 
 59, 59, 59, 59, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69), BMI = c(23.8, 23.8, 23.8, 
 23.8, 23.8, 29.8, 29.8, 29.8, 29.8, 29.8), time = c(0, 1, 3, 
 5, 6, 0, 1, 3, 5, 6), variable = c(5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 3, 2, NA, 10, 
 1)), .Names = c("ID", "AGE", "BMI", "time", "var"), row.names = c(NA, 
 10L), class = "data.frame")

   > df
      ID AGE  BMI time      var
   1   1  59 23.8    0        5
   2   1  59 23.8    1        6
   3   1  59 23.8    3        1
   4   1  59 23.8    5        6
   5   1  59 23.8    6        2
   6   2  69 29.8    0        3
   7   2  69 29.8    1        2
   8   2  69 29.8    3       NA
   9   2  69 29.8    5       10
   10  2  69 29.8    6        1
```

AGE and BMI are baseline variables, var is longitudinal variable measured at different time points (time). 
I would like to extract baseline (time = 0) data  from var variable and create new baseline variable var.baseline. My data frame is going to look like

```
   > df
     ID AGE  BMI time variable var.baseline
 1   1  59 23.8    0        5            5
 2   1  59 23.8    1        6            5
 3   1  59 23.8    3        1            5
 4   1  59 23.8    5        6            5
 5   1  59 23.8    6        2            5
 6   2  69 29.8    0        3            3
 7   2  69 29.8    1        2            3
 8   2  69 29.8    3       NA            3
 9   2  69 29.8    5       10            3
 10  2  69 29.8    6        1            3
```

Of course, I can transform the data to wide format, create var.baseline based on variable.0, and then again transform  to long format. However, as my real data set is significantly larger and  I have much more variables, it becomes cumbersome. Could you please suggest a more easy way of extracting baseline data from long format data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(var.baseline=var[time==0])
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[,var.baseline:=var[time==0] , by=ID]
```

Or using `base R`

```
 merge(df,setNames(subset(df, time==0,select=c("ID", "var")),
                c('ID', 'var.baseline')), by='ID')
```

Or

```
 library(zoo)
 df$var.baseline <- with(df, na.locf(var[!NA^time==0]))
```

Comment: When I'm using your R base solution, R is dropping some rows. Any ideas? Edit: I found it, I had to add all=TRUE.

Comment: @kim Yes, by default, `merge` is doing inner join